# Selenium Python3, how to click on a div to fully load the html?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use *Selenium* and *BeautifulSoup* to extract some information from https://superbet.ro/pariuri-sportive/live.
I created the urls for the live matches, and now I'm iterating through them to extract some statistics. But [STASTISTICS TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlTwk.png) is not loading when I use this code:

```
def get_soup(url):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(3)
   
    page = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
    driver.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
    return soup
```

So I'm trying to click the Statistics button to find the divs I need, because the html obtained in my script is partially loaded and different than the original one from the chrome developer tools.

Here are the difference between what I get and what I need:

```
<div class="statistics__content">
<div class="sa-sdk-v5">
<div class="sa-sdk-unknown-tab" eventdetails="[object Object]">
```

[Here are the divs I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5DOA.png)

I don't know exactly how to click on Statistics because I don't have any button tag.

[Here are the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdwmF.png)

Finally, I solved the problem by clicking on that tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say stick with Selenium for that process.
You will need to:

1. Locate the element using selenium. In your case, you will need to grab all the matches and then go to its relative path to find out the box that you can click on. I don't think it has to be a button.
2. Then you can use something like this.

```
def wait_for_field(self, xpath, driver, interval=10):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, interval).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        except Exception as e:
            raise CrawlerException(field + " failed, ", str(e))
        return elemenT    
def click_on_match(self, page_browser):
        try:
            element_to_click= self.wait_for_field("**fill out here**", page_browser,
                                                     interval=5)
            print("found match to click")
            page_browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element_to_click)
        except:
            pass'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
url = "https://old.superbet.ro/rest/SBWeb.Models.Casino/getAllGames"

r = requests.get(url)
json_data = r.json()
```